# How to write conditional logic using ant-contrib 

Tags: ant, if-statement, depends

I am a beginner in ANT.

What am I doing wrong? ant-contrib-1.0b3 , is available. I would like to call the default target as follows:

```
<target name="build">
<if>
 <equals arg1="${config.name}" arg2="foo" />
 <then>
   <depends="get-all-war,..." />
 </then>
 <elseif>
 <equals arg1="${config.name}" arg2="mark" />
 <then>
   <depends="zip-wars, ..." />
 </then>
 </elseif>
 <else>
    <depends="get-all-war, zip-wars, docs, deleteAll" />
 </else>
</if>
```

Comment: @ HashMaper : you have got an answer. Please come back, accept the answer, up-vote if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same thing smartly using macros. If your targets get-all-war, zip-wars, docs, deleteAll take more time you can run them in parallel like this :

```
<target name="build">
  <if>
  <equals arg1="${config.name}" arg2="foo" />
  <then>
    <mGetAllWar/>
  </then>
  <elseif>
  <equals arg1="${config.name}" arg2="mark" />
  <then>
    <mZipWars />
  </then>
  </elseif>
  <else>
    <mRestAllTargets/>
  </else>
</if>

<mGetAllWar>
  <parallel>
    <antcall name="target1">
    <antcall name="target2">
    ... 
  </parallel>
</mGetAllWar>

<mZipWars >
  <parallel>
    <antcall name="target1">
    <antcall name="target2">
    ... 
  </parallel>
</mZipWars >

<mRestAllTargets>
  <parallel>
    <antcall name="target1">
    <antcall name="target2">
    ... 
  </parallel>
</mRestAllTargets>
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to use [antcall](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) to execute other targets.

```
<target name="build">
<if>
 <equals arg1="${config.name}" arg2="foo" />
 <then>
   <antcall target="get-all-war" />
   <antcall target="..." />
 </then>
 <elseif>
 <equals arg1="${config.name}" arg2="mark" />
 <then>
   <antcall target="zip-wars" />
   <antcall target="..." />
 </then>
 </elseif>
 <else>
   <antcall target="get-all-war" />
   <antcall target="zip-wars" />
   <antcall target="docs" />
   <antcall target="deleteAll" />
 </else>
</if>
```